# HTML Email Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: html, image, html-table, html-email

I'm having an issue with an email I am coding that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I have an area that appears alright when viewing the HTML file in the browser but GMail and browsers like Firefox and IE are causing some problems. Alignments get screwed up, images don't sit in the right place, etc. I think the problem I am having is that in certain browsers my right column with text gets pushed beneath my bullet column. I was wondering if any can find some flaws in my code that might help me. Here's the section that's giving me trouble:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ISSGT 2013</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--Header-->
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:0px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://www.ieee-isgt.org"><img src="header.jpg" alt="Header" height="86" width="600" style="display:block;border:0;vertical-align:bottom;"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--Headline-->
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="background-color:#436ead; padding-top:10px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:30px;">

<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:19px;line-height:22px;font-weight:normal;color:#fff;text-align:center;margin-top:-15px;">The 4th Annual IEEE PES Conference on<br />Innovative Smart Grid Technologies is less than<br /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:44px;line-height:43px;font-weight:bold;color:#fff;text-align:center;">6 WEEKS AWAY!</span></td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>    

<!--Body-->
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:10px; vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
<td width="540" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:17px;line-height:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#141313;text-align:left;">Very soon, hundreds of your colleagues &#8211; smart grid practitioners, executives, researchers and policy makers &#8211; will gather in Washington D.C. to review and discuss ground&#8211;breaking innovations in smart grid technologies.</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table align="center" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:10px;vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
<td align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:0px;vertical-align:top;">
```

```
<table width="540" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:10px;vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
<td height="auto" width="540" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:17px;line-height:18px;font-weight:normal;color:#141313;text-align:left;margin-top:10px">In addition to the impressive roster of keynote speakers, and presentations by recognized leaders in the field, here are some compelling reasons <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:17px;line-height:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#141313;text-align:left;">why you MUST attend this year’s event&#58;        </span></td>
</tr>
</table>


<!--Container-->
<table height="auto" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:15px;border-collapase:0px;vertical-align:top;">
<tr>

<!--Image-->
<td height="298" width="243" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;border-collapse:0px;"><img src="dc1.jpg" alt="Washington DC" height="298px" width="243px" style="display:block;border:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:bottom;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"/></td>



<!--Bullet Container-->
<td style="vertical-align:top;border:0;border-collapse:0;">
<table height="auto" width="357" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;border-collapse:0px;float:right;display:inline;">


<!-- Bullet 1-->

<tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-collapse:0px;">&bull;</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">RESULTS&#58;</span>Learn about real-practice technology, deployment experience, and customer acceptance issues related to smart grid.</td>
</tr>


<!-- Bullet 2-->
<tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">&bull;</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">NETWORKING&#58;</span>Meet and speak directly with industry leaders, regulators and entrepreneurs working with the smart grid.</td>
</tr>

<!-- Bullet 3-->
<tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">&bull;</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">OPPORTUNITY&#58;</span>International speakers will report on real success stories and pitfalls – as well as current business.</td>
</tr>

<!-- Bullet 4-->
<tr>

<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">&bull;    </td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">RESEARCH&#58;</span>Noted academics and practitioners talk candidly about their work in making smart grid a cost-effective proposition.</td>
</tr>

</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table height="auto" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:0px;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;">
<tr>
<td><img src="dc2.jpg" alt="Washington DC" height="48px" width="600px" style="display:block;border:0;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="600px" height="auto" align="center" style="background-color:#168116;vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:27px;line-height:31px;color:#fff;text-align:center;padding-top:30px;">SEATS ARE FILLING UP FAST!
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:0px;">
<a href="http://www.isgtreg.com"><img src="button2.jpg" alt="Register" height="48" width="312" style="border:0px;vertical-align:top;"/></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;color:#fff;text-align:center;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">For more information on programs<br />and speakers, visit <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-style:italic;line-height:17px;color:#fff;"><a href="http://www.ieee-isgt.org" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;">www.ieee-isgt.org</a></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--Footer-->
<table height="auto" width="600" border="0" align="center" style="margin-top:5px;">

<tr>
<td height="auto" width="auto" align="center" style="background-color:#e5e4e4; padding-top:10px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:30px;">
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#3e3e3e;text-align:left;">ISGT 2013 conference co-sponsoring societies include IEEE-USA, IEEE Dielectrics and Electrical Insulation Society, IEEE Industry Applications Society, IEEE Industrial Electronics Society, IEEE Power Electronics Society, IEEE Systems Council and IEEE Signal Processing Society.</p>
</td>
</tr>


<!--Unsubscribe-->
<tr>
<td height="40" width="600" align="center">
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:14px;font-weight:normal;color:#141313;text-align:center;">If you no longer wish to receive these types of messages from IEEE PES Media,<br />please <a href="/" style="color:#168116;text-decoration:none;">click here</a> or fax 703-860-1623, or write 445 Hoes Lane, Piscataway, N.J. 08854.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[How it should look...](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/908/screenshot20130122at112.png)

Here's it it appears in the browsers as an HTML file, which is how I want it to appear in every instance. If anyone can put out something blaring that I am missing I would really appreciate it.

Comment: One comment: when you use images in emails you should use the full path.  Also, can you post the whole HTML?

Comment: Updated with the full email.

Comment: @DanKanze but this is HTML email. For these things it is still 1999

Comment: I believe it may have something to do with my column of text and column with bullets. The text column is appearing beneath each bullet instead of next to them in certain browsers/email clients.

Comment: @graham He isn't using a muilticolumn layout. Only muilticolumn layouts require the use of tables. DIV's are wholesomely supported for single column layouts. He can using a fixed background image on the parent and children can be single columns. You lose support for this however in Android + Outlook. If you do want complete cross browser layout I would recoomend a collapse broder (supported on all broswers) and a 4 quadrant grid. using the list below for the top right quadrant, images to build the background for the topleft, bottom left, and bottom right.

Comment: oh, you deleted your comment?! I was only being cheeky. You're right about the layouts but I'd imagine he/she would need it to work in Outlook too. Your answer looks right though, @user2000978 have you tried that (with inline styles like Dan mentions?)

Comment: @graham I forgot for a moment about the CSS limitations, so yea I removed my initial comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.content span{color:green;}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="topleft_background.png"/>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <ul class="content">
            <li><span>Green Text:</span> Regular text.</li>
            <li><span>Green Text:</span> Regular text.</li>
            <li><span>Green Text:</span> Regular text.</li>
            <li><span>Green Text:</span> Regular text.</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="bottomleft_background.png"/>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <img src="bottomright_background.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This let me get rid of one of my tables which is helpful, but the style is not carrying over to all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest [mailrox.com](http://mailrox.com)

Does all this sort of thing for you.

Edit:

try this:

```
<html style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important;"><head>



   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title></title>
</head><body style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; text-shadow: none; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; background-color: #FEFEFE; margin: 0px 0 0 0px; padding: 0px 0 0;" bgcolor="#FEFEFE"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; background-color: #FEFEFE; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;" bgcolor="#FEFEFE">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none;">
            <td valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none;">
                <table width="603" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none;">
                                <td width="603">
                                    <table width="603" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border: 0px none;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none;">
                                                <td width="603">
                                                    <table width="603" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border: 0px none;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; height: 20px; border: 0;"><td width="603" valign="top" height="20" align="left" style="background-color: #FEFEFE;" bgcolor="#FEFEFE"><img width="1" height="20" style="display: block; line-height: 1; opacity: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0;" src="images/clear.gif" alt=""></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; background-color: #FEFEFE; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0; border: 0;" bgcolor="#FEFEFE"><tbody><tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;">
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;">
                            <table width="603" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0; border: 0;">
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;">
        <td width="603">
            <table width="603" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;"><td width="242" height="376" align="left" valign="top" style="">


            <img height="376" src="images/image-268344-530390.jpg" style="display: block; line-height: 1; padding: 0; border: 0;" width="242">

</td>
<td width="361" align="left" valign="top">
    <table width="361" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0; border: 0;">
        <tbody>
                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;">
        <td width="361">
            <table width="361" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;"><td width="361" height="257" align="left" valign="top" style="">


            <table height="auto" width="357" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;border-collapse:0px;float:right;display:inline;">


<!-- Bullet 1-->

<tbody><tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-collapse:0px;">•</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">RESULTS:</span>Learn about real-practice technology, deployment experience, and customer acceptance issues related to smart grid.</td>
</tr>


<!-- Bullet 2-->
<tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">•</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">NETWORKING:</span>Meet and speak directly with industry leaders, regulators and entrepreneurs working with the smart grid.</td>
</tr>

<!-- Bullet 3-->
<tr>
<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;text-align:left;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">•</td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">OPPORTUNITY:</span>International speakers will report on real success stories and pitfalls – as well as current business.</td>
</tr>

<!-- Bullet 4-->
<tr>

<td height="auto" width="8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;border-collapse:0px;">•    </td>

<td height="auto" width="311" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;color:#141313;float:right;text-align:left:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:30px;"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;color:#168116;text-align:left;margin-right:3px;">RESEARCH:</span>Noted academics and practitioners talk candidly about their work in making smart grid a cost-effective proposition.</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>

</td>
</tr>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
  </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;">
        <td width="361">
            <table width="361" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0;"><td width="361" height="119" align="left" valign="top" style="">


            <img height="119" src="images/image-268346-530393.jpg" style="display: block; line-height: 1; padding: 0; border: 0;" width="361">

</td>
</tr>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
  </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
  </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody></table>

<style type="text/css">
body { width: 100% !important; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; }
body { background-color: #FEFEFE !important; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; font-family: sans-serif !important; }
body { letter-spacing: normal !important; word-spacing: 0px !important; margin-top: 0 !important; padding-top: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; margin-bottom: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important; padding-left: 0 !important; text-shadow: none !important; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 13px !important; line-height: 17px !important; font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !important; }
</style>




</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help DickieBoy, but the same issues still exist when sending a test out to an email client in Firefox on a PC laptop...not on a Mac desktop though.

Comment: I would look at your bullet table, everything around that is perfect. 

Here is what i would try:
Fix all heights, take the autos out. 
Remove the vertical aligns. and any margins(use the width of the sibling td) 
When you say Firefox? you mean Thunderbird?